# iPhone SDK: How to extract specific text from a textview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, uitextview

I have a textview that already has text extracted from a website. So, let's say the text in the text view has this text:

```
Save Location 

84°F 

Clear 

Feels like 90°F
```

In this text, how can I extract the text that says 84 in the "84°F" to a string? Remember that the 84 is a constantly changing variable from the website so sometimes it'll be a different number and I can't search for the number directly. If you know how to do this please let me know :) Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
NSString *originalString = @"Save Location 84°F Clear Feels like 90°F";

NSMutableString *stringWithNums = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:originalString.length];

NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:originalString];
NSCharacterSet *numbers = [NSCharacterSet 
                       characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];

while ([scanner isAtEnd] == NO) {
    NSString *buffer;
    if ([scanner scanCharactersFromSet:numbers intoString:&buffer]) {
        [stringWithNums appendString:buffer];

    } else {
        [scanner setScanLocation:([scanner scanLocation] + 1)];
        [stringWithNums appendString:@" "];
    }
}
```

Now `stringWithNums` will contains something like this:

> 84   (some spaces)   90

Then you could parse `stringWithNums` like this:

```
NSArray *tempArray = [stringWithNums componentsSeparatedByString: @" "];
NSString *finalTemperature;

for(int index = 0; index < [tempArray count]; index++){

    if([[tempArray objectAtIndex:index] intValue] != 0 && [[tempArray objectAtIndex:index] intValue] < 200){
        finalTemperature = [tempArray objectAtIndex: index];
        break;
    }
}
```

`finalTemperature` will contain "84". You could put this in method form and pass in `originalString` as an argument so you could reuse this code. Hope this helps and if you have any questions, make sure to ask in the comments!

UPDATE:
I added this line:
    && [[tempArray objectAtIndex:index] intValue] < 200

to the if statement above, so it now looks like this:

```
if([[tempArray objectAtIndex:index] intValue] != 0 && [[tempArray objectAtIndex:index] intValue] < 200){
```

In the website text, it looks like the only number before the "82" is a zip code, which is 5 digits long. In reality, all temperatures (on Earth) are below 200 (3 digits), so the extra line I put in makes sure that the final temperature is a three or less digit number and not a 5 digit zip code.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @iNoob - Thanks. Your way was great; it just did not account for very low temperatures (<10) and very high temperatures (>99). Otherwise, I would've suggested your method as the answer.

Comment: Wow thanks! This worked great but the final result was that finalTemperature was equal to @"". tempArray was equal to @"35 objects" and stringWithNums was equal to @"    84         90" everything seemed to go right until the end.  Not really sure why the final result was @"".Also I will need this to work for temperature over 99 and under 10. Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes you can do it tomorrow no problem at all, than you very much.

Comment: so have you been able to test and see what the problem is?

Comment: @mrprogrammer I just fixed it! I'm updating the code in my answer.

Comment: So I tested it and it worked perfectly with the text I put, but when I tested it with the website there a lot more text and a lot more numbers. so it seems to be getting the first digits of numbers it sees in text. so lets say I have this:
McAllen, TX (78504)
Weather
Save Location
90°F
Mostly Cloudy
Feels like 98°F

In this text its getting 78504 as the number in final temperature. So how can I fix this? Thank you very ugh for your help.

Comment: @mrprogrammer - When you test it with the website, you said there's a lot more text. Could you post a complete sample of what the text from the website would look like? Thanks.

Comment: This is the complete text:

`Add a location
United States (English)
Sign in
Weather
Local
National Forecast
severe weather
Alerts
Hurricane Central
Share Tweet
McAllen, TX (78504)
Weather
Save Location
82°F
Partly Cloudy
Feels like 87°F`

and theres a lot more. But the point is that I'm getting 78504 as the final answer instead of 82. is seems to be getting the first pair of numbers. Could you please show me how I can get the 82 as the final answer. Thanks very much in advance

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked perfectly :D. Sorry to bother you any further, but for the text I sent you in the comment before, how could I extract "McAllen" from all that text? Thanks so much for your help :)

Comment: @mrprogrammer - Since that is the only text with a comma following it, you could parse the text and identify the string with a comma right after it. I'll post some code demonstrating this later.